# understanding geometry of eigen values of Ricci tensor

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As per I can visualize the eigen value $\lambda$ of a linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$,  defined by $Tv=\lambda v$, is actually the scaling factor of the vector in the same direction as of $v$.My question is how to visualize the eigenvalues of a Ricci tensor on a Riemannian manifold? Then what kind of estimate one can obtain from the lowest eigenvalue?

Comment: There's a theorem that self-adjoint linear maps can be diagonalized via an orthogonal matrix.  You can re-interpret this as a theorem about bilinear functions, that they can be diagonalized orthogonally.  That gives you your interpretation.

Comment: But what geometric estimate does those eigenvalues gives?

Comment: If you fix a vector $v$, then, up to a scalar factor, $Rc(v,v)$ is the average sectional curvature of tangent 2-planes containing $v$

Comment: The lowest eigenvalue gives you a lower bound of the Ricci tensor's values (with input on the unit sphere).  Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: yes I got it.Can you give me some reference where this is clarified vastly.